# Which is the correct dm-cache version

Tags: linux, cache, device-mapper, bcache

I am trying to install dm-cache on my CentOS machine. Which dm-cache version should I use. I read on wikipedia as below:

> Another dm-cache project with similar goals was announced by Eric Van
>   Hensbergen and Ming Zhao in 2006, as the result of an internship work
>   at IBM.[8]
>
> Later, Joe Thornber, Heinz Mauelshagen and Mike Snitzer provided their
>   own implementation of the concept, which resulted in the inclusion of
>   dm-cache into the Linux kernel. dm-cache was merged into the Linux
>   kernel mainline in kernel version 3.9, which was released on April 28,
>   2013.[6][9]

dm-cache is integrated  in the mainline of linux kernel. And also dm-cache was written by Joe Thornber, Heinz Mauelshagen and Mike Snitzer and another was written by Eric Van Hensbergen and Ming Zhao, so which one should I use, are both the same, both the version differ in the way it has to be setup.
Has any one tried to use both the versions?

Answer (score 0):

The original implementation of dm-cache was [submitted to the Linux kernel mailing list in 2006](https://lkml.org/lkml/2006/11/27/190) but it doesn't appear that it got very far towards being included in the kernel at that time. Ming Zhao did continue development of his code [and it even made it into production use.](https://web.archive.org/web/20160202123356/http://visa.cs.fiu.edu:80/tiki/dm-cache)

[In 2010 it was brought up again](https://listman.redhat.com/archives/dm-devel/2010-March/012648.html) but by that time the developers of the current dm-cache in the kernel had already made significant progress on that project. It appears to be a new independent project though it's confusing that they both used the same name.

From [the archive of the university's page](https://web.archive.org/web/20160202123356/http://visa.cs.fiu.edu:80/tiki/dm-cache) it seems that they considered kernel 3.9 with dm-cache made their own dm-cache somewhat obsolete and planned to focus on new research rather than continuing to support their separate dm-cache.

Although it appears that [Ming Zhao has not completely abandoned his dm-cache project,](https://github.com/mingzhao/dm-cache) it seems to have gone back to being more of a research project. There has been far more work put into the Linux kernel's dm-cache and its integration with LVM, so you are much more likely to find good resources and support with that.